# What are the roots of $\sin(ax) + \sin((a + 2)x)$?

Tags: trigonometry, roots

I was playing around with $\sin(5x) + \sin(7x)$, wondering where the roots of the function are. I [graphed it on wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%285x%29%20%2B%20sin%287x%29%20%3D%200) and from the list of solutions I guessed that the solutions to $\sin(5x) + \sin(7x) = 0$ are [exactly the roots of $\sin(6x)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%286x%29%20%3Dsin%285x%29%20%2B%20sin%287x%29).

After playing around with similar values, I have to wonder, is it true that solving

$$\sin(a\cdot x) + \sin((a + 2)\cdot x) = 0$$

is equivalent to

$$\sin((a + 1)\cdot x) = 0$$

---

This problem seems to want induction.

It is true that the roots of $\sin(x) + \sin(3x)$ are the same roots as $\sin(2x)$ (again checked via wolframalpha). So that takes care of the base case.

However, I have no idea how to get from the $\sin(a\cdot x) + \sin((a+2)\cdot x)$ to the $\sin((a+1)\cdot x)$ for any $a$. It's just been guesswork.

---

Is it true that $\sin(a\cdot x) + \sin((a + 2)\cdot x)$ has the same roots as $\sin((a + 1)\cdot x)$?

Comment: Hahaha, I wondered if someone would want to Latexify the title. I personally felt that there was no big reason to do so.

Comment: Oops I forgot to say that I was expecting $a\in\mathbb N$

Comment: Just OCD stuff. I took a bit longer to answer because I was deducing the transformation again right now (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is really nothing special about the pair $(a,a+2)$, so we look at $\sin(ax)+\sin(bx)=0$, or equivalently $\sin(ax)=\sin(-bx)$.

When are the sines of two numbers equal? We have $\sin s=\sin t$ if $t$ is of the form $s+2k\pi$, or if $t$ is of the form $\pi-s+2k\pi$, with $k$ an arbitrary integer.

Now we can write down the general solution of $\sin(ax)=\sin(-bx)$.

Comment: Thanks for answering the bigger question behind my question.

Comment: You are welcome. Sum to product identities will also do the job, but I thought perhaps something more closely connected to the fundamental symmetries might be interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Note the sum to product identity: $\sin A + \sin B = 2\sin \dfrac{A+B}{2}\cos \dfrac{A-B}{2}$.

Hence, $\sin(ax) + \sin((a+2)x) = 2\sin((a+1)x)\cos(x)$.

So the roots of $\sin(ax) + \sin((a+2)x)$ are the roots of $\sin((a+1)x)$ along with the roots of $\cos(x)$.

If $x = \dfrac{\pi}{2}+\pi k$ (the roots of $\cos x$) are also roots of $\sin((a+1)x)$, then we are only left with the roots of $\sin((a+1)x)$. This happens iff $\sin\left((a+1)(\dfrac{\pi}{2}+\pi k)\right) = 0$, i.e. $a$ is odd (assuming $a \in \mathbb{Z}$).

Here are the [graphs](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%282x%29%2Bsin%284x%29%20%3D%20sin%283x%29) of $\sin(2x)+\sin(4x)$ and $\sin(3x)$. Note that $\sin(2x)+\sin(4x)$ has more roots.

Comment: Oh, that's the identity I was missing in Wikipedia's fat list of trigonometric identities. No wonder why this seemed impossible.

Comment: Cool. I incorrectly saw the graph for $\sin(2x) + \sin(4x)$ and $\sin(3x)$, but on every odd $a$ I tried, this worked. That's cool.

Answer (score 1):

We transform that sum into a product. An easy way to deduce it is: We begin with $\sin X + \sin Y$. Let $X = c + d$ and $Y = c - d$. This gives us $c = \frac{X + Y}{2}$ and $d = \frac{X - Y}{2}$. This way: $$\begin{align} \sin X + \sin Y &= \sin(c+d)+ \sin(c-d) \\ &= \sin c \cos d + \sin c \cos d + \sin c \cos d - \sin d \cos c \\ &= 2 \sin c \cos d \\ &= 2 \sin\left(\frac{X+Y}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{X-Y}{2}\right)\end{align}$$
Making $X = ax$ and $Y = (a+2)x$ gives: $$\sin(ax) + \sin((a+2)x) = 2\sin((a+1)x))\cos(-x) = 2\sin((a+1)x)~\cos(x)$$
since $\cos$ is an even function.

Comment: I edited the answer, thought it was better to use $c$ and $d$ instead of $a$ and $b$ to avoid a possible confusion with the specific "$a$" of your question.